# Propriedade e Objeto JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Porque ele não consegue ler a propriedade?

```js
objetoSelecionado = document.selectForm.variosDias;
```

```html
<form name="selectForm">
    <select name="variosDias" multiple>
        <option value="Domingo">Domingo</option>
        <option value="Segunda">Segunda-feira</option>
        <option value="Terça">Terça-feira</option>
        <option value="Quarta">Quarta-feira</option>
        <option value="Quinta">Quinta-feira</option>
        <option value="Sexta">Sexta-feira</option>
        <option value="Sábado">Sábado</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="Enviar" onclick="">
</form>
```

Aparece o erro:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'variosDias' of undefined

Comment: O que você quer ler exatamente? o valor selecionado ou o DOM?

Comment: o DOM, eu queria saber onde está o Erro

Comment: Que erro está aparecendo pra você? Aqui está funcionando normalmente...

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'variosDias' of undefined

Comment: Vou criar uma resposta com um exemplo pra você ver como tá funcionando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido! coloquei o código JavaScript, logo após o formulário, e não apareceu mais erro. Obrigado para todos!

```html
<form name="selectForm">
    <select name="variosDias" multiple>
        <option value="Domingo">Domingo</option>
        <option value="Segunda">Segunda-feira</option>
        <option value="Terça">Terça-feira</option>
        <option value="Quarta">Quarta-feira</option>
        <option value="Quinta">Quinta-feira</option>
        <option value="Sexta">Sexta-feira</option>
        <option value="Sábado">Sábado</option>
     </select>
</form>
<script>
    objetoSelecionado = document.selectForm.variosDias;
    console.log(objetoSelecionado);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você está no caminho certo! Quando você seleciona dessa forma: `document.selectForm.variosDia` você está selecionando apenas o elemento HTML, se quer acessar o valor dele, deve colocar `document.selectForm.variosDia.value`. Lembrando que o algo deve estar selecionado para exibir, se não, retornará um valor vazio ;)

Este [Codepen](https://codepen.io/victorjordan95/pen/qYjBqM?editors=1010) pode te ajudar a entender melhor!

Answer (score 0):

O exemplo está funcionando:

```js
objetoSelecionado = document.selectForm.variosDias;

console.log(objetoSelecionado)

objetoSelecionado.remove()
```

```html
<form name="selectForm">
    <select name="variosDias" multiple>
        <option value="Domingo">Domingo</option>
        <option value="Segunda">Segunda-feira</option>
        <option value="Terça">Terça-feira</option>
        <option value="Quarta">Quarta-feira</option>
        <option value="Quinta">Quinta-feira</option>
        <option value="Sexta">Sexta-feira</option>
        <option value="Sábado">Sábado</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="Enviar" onclick="">
</form>
```

Verifique se o seu código completo não possui elementos com o mesmo name, ou se os names estão escritos corretamente.